# Django loaddata ignore existing objects

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures, loaddata

I have a fixture with list of entries. eg:

```
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "currency": 1,
      "price": "99.99",
      "product_variant": 1
    },
    "model": "products.productprice",
    "pk": 1
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "currency": 2,
      "price": "139.99",
      "product_variant": 1
    },
    "model": "products.productprice",
    "pk": 2
  }
]
```

This is only initial data for each entry (The price might change). I would like to be able to add another entry to that fixture and load it with `loaddata` but without updating entries that already exist in the database.

Is there any way to do that? Something like `--ignorenonexistent` but for existing entries.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep pk in the json like that, you will always overwrite the first two records in product.productprice.

I would use "pk: null".
This way, you will always create new record with every load.

So if you want to create a new price:

```
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "currency": 1,
      "price": "99.99",
      "product_variant": 1
    },
    "model": "products.productprice",
    "pk": 1
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "currency": 2,
      "price": "139.99",
      "product_variant": 1
    },
    "model": "products.productprice",
    "pk": 2
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "currency": 4,
      "price": "9.99",
      "product_variant": 1
    },
    "model": "products.productprice",
    "pk": null
  }
]
```

The first two records are always be the same, but if you already added a third one ( pk:3 ) with the last section you will create a new productprice with pk: 4.

BTW: if your **currency** field is an other primary key(with autoincrement), you can put "null" there too, a new primary key will be generated.